# If I were a [nuclear-power] I'd rename this tag

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, retagging

Some people have used [nuclear-power](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nuclear-power) to refer to nuclear weapons ([nuclear-weapons](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nuclear-weapons)), possibly because governments that have nukes are called a "nuclear power", as opposed to energy generated by nuclear reactors. [1](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/105104/uranium-block-house-heating) [2](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/57414/how-a-nuclear-war-in-north-hemisphere-would-affect-the-south-hemisphere) [3](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/39333/what-are-some-examples-of-magic-equivalent-of-a-nuke) [4](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/62541/realistic-world-war-iii-between-china-and-the-us)

Should we rename [nuclear-power](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nuclear-power) to "nuclear-energy" to reduce the likelihood of misuse?

Comment: *"Some people have used"* - please, post  links if that's the case.

Comment: @Molot I’m not at a computer right now, but check my recent edit history.

Comment: @Mołot I've added links.

Comment: "Uranium block house heating" is  clearly  **not**  about weapons. 3 and 4 are closed - they have many issues, so it's more about these specific questions than a tag. This leaves **one relevant example** of bad tag usage per  37 questions tagged. I don't  see it as a real issue.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's necessary.

A quick glance through the questions tagged [nuclear-power](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nuclear-power) don't show a single misconception.  They're all about the use of nuclear power, not about a nation being, politically, a "nuclear power."  The tag description is pretty clear, too.

I suspect this issue would be more germain to [Politics.SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/), where both discussions could occur with realtively equal frequency, than here, where a question about a nation being a nuclear-power might occur, say, once in every 10,000 tag uses.

Comment: That’s because I recently retagged a few questions.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, how many?

Comment: four questions.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, hmmm... 10% out of (then) 41 questions.  Kinda blows away my 1:10,000 number, but it's still not a lot.  There's only two subscriers following the tag.

Comment: For the sake of 4 questions those able to retag should retag and not worry too much. Nuclear power is clearer and a more conventional term than nuclear energy so the tag would re-emerge fairly quickly.

Comment: @Separatrix   I'd argue    it's   for the sake of 1  question, maybe 3,   as nuclear  heating is [tag:nuclear-power]  all  right  and 2 others are already closed anyway (question was updated with actual links).